# I differentiated and drew the graph. It is right?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, differentiation, displacement

Draw the velocity time graph when the displacement of the particle obeys the relation $$s=4+5t+2t^2.$$

Comment: Please guide me. if acceleration is given as a function of time. Can I integrate it and draw the corresponding velocity and time values. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is the first derivative of displacement with respect to time. So, on differentiating, you get $v$, which should be a linear curve for this case, as your velocity. If you integrate the area under this curve, you will get back to your displacement. To get the acceleration of the particle, you need to differentiate it again, for it is the second derivative of displacement.

Comment: It site policy not to give worked answers to homework-type questions (or check-my-work questions).